# Why does parseFloat('0.0') or parseInt('0.0) returns false

Tags: javascript

While parsing the inputs i came across this behaviour of javascript

if you parse a number

```
console.log(parseFloat('562.0') ? 'true' : 'false') 
console.log(parseInt('562') ? 'true' : 'false')
```

It returns true, but if i parse 0

```
console.log(parseFloat('0.00') ? 'true' : 'false') 
console.log(parseInt('0') ? 'true' : 'false')
```

it returns false

can any one please explain why this happens ??

Comment: Both will return 0, which is somewhat equivalent to false (programmation basics)

Comment: @Justinas: It would be more correct to say `ToBoolean(0) === false`. Because even though `"   " == false`, `ToBoolean("   ") === true`. I know... nitpicking ;)

Comment: @FelixKling in php: `$a = '5.something'; in_array($a, [5, 1, '1.nothing']);` will return true, so it's possible to make lots of expressions to be equal to false. It's only basic comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. parseFloat returns false if we have non numeric value i was thinking on that line and got confused. Moderators can delete this question as i think it is not of stackoverflow standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesent return **boolean false** it return **number 0** in ternary operator you compare with 0. **0 is false**

Answer (score 4):

When you use the conditional operator `? :`, according to [ECMA-262 §11.12](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12), the first operand (in your case it's the `Number` returned by`parseInt` or `parseFloat`) is converted to `Boolean`.

Conversion goes according to [ECMA-262 §9.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2), which says

> Number - The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN; otherwise the result is true.

That's why your expressions with 562 evalute to true, and expressions with 0 evalute to false.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it returns 0. But, in javascript zero means false.

Answer (score 0):

0 and 1 is boolean. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean

```
console.log((true)+0); // 1
console.log((false)+0); // 0
```

Zero is the only number returns false.

```
console.log((1) ? "true" : "false"); //true
console.log((0) ? "true" : "false"); //false
```